# iOS Simulator connection timed out

Tags: ios, xcode, ios-simulator

When I try to simulate my iOS app using Xcode version 9.4 simulator, it keeps on loading and loading till it sends me the following message:

> Failed to initiate service connection to simulator. Connection timed out

My Internet is fast and I have updated my macOS HighSeirra 10.13.4 in no time.

Comment: reset simulator data

Comment: Internet connection doesn’t affect connection to Simulator

Comment: I have seen three causes: `1:` When you are on a Mac that has too little memory (<=4GiB) and so memory is being swapped to disk when both Xcode and the Simulator are open; `2:` A slow hard disk (non-SSD); `3:` A non-Administrator account where the connection times out while you are entering the Admin password. `Solution:` In all three cases you just have to wait for the simulator to load correctly (and any Admin passwords entered) and then try to run the app in the Simulator again - it should connect fine. You can also connect to the running simulator inside Xcode (Debug->Attach to Process).

Comment: @RoboticCat seems to be right, in my case in this machine I'm very low on free memory (< 500 MB) and it usually happens the first time I run the app on simulator. In my case to solve it, I just have to do one of this 3 things (all work): free some more memory, or run the app again; or attach the simulator processor; and then the app runs ok on simuiator.

If you're a "slow" and low memory machine I would recommend you to use a real device, it works far better and faster than the simulator.

Comment: Any iOS 12 simulator under Xcode 10 stalls for me. All other non-iOS 12 simulators work fine. It does not matter what project, or if they were cleaned by code menu or cleaned by deleting the derived data folder.

Answer (score 2):

**Close** Xcode Properly (from your dock as well )

**Close** simulator

And **Restart** Xcode and Simulator.

Let it build & index the project

And it should work fine after that..

**Thanks**

**Happy Coding ;)**

P.S. Clear Derived Data , if above steps didn't work for you.

Answer (score -1):

**Close** Simulator.

Try **Clean** your project and **Run** again.

If it does not help try **restart XCode**

Is it does not help try **reboot your Mac**

P.S. Please check if you have only **one** running copy of simulator

Answer (score -1):

Clean your project [By pressing Command+Option+Shift+K] or [Command+Shift+K]. This will solve your issue.

Comment: i don't have an apple keyboard.Actually i am using Vmware player on windows. How can i press "command "

Comment: Then try, there is a windows button. Click windows+shift+k.